# Adding ellipsis to a String added to ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

My code is failing to add ellipsis to the end of a string which then is being added to an ArrayList. All what I am get is "[Select a color&#8230]" and not "[Select a color...]" which what I am after.

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

arrayList.add("[Select a color&#8230]");

Collections.addAll(arrayList, data);

arrayList.add("more colors later");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your entity lacks a semicolon after the number.

Comment: ";" deliberately removed from the post, but is present in the code.

Comment: Ah. Why don't you just use the characters "..."?

Comment: 3 instead of one? I could but not good coding if I can help it.

Comment: True, but here's the comparison: the pain of spending time solving the problem vs. Two bytes. I don't know much about Android Dev; can you use entities as such?